# applicationDidBecomeActive firing on deactivation on iPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone-x

Is anyone else having trouble with `applicationDidBecomeActive` incorrectly firing on *deactivation* of the app on the new iPhone X?

Here's my test app:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(fired),
            name: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,
            object: nil
        )
    }

    @objc func fired(_:Any) {
        print("fired")
    }

}
```

Run the app on the iPhone X simulator. Naturally, I see "fired" in the console. So far, so good. Now swipe the home indicator sideways or up, to switch to a different app or to bring up the app switcher. I see "fired" appear again in the console!

This seems just wrong, and is throwing all of my apps into a kerfuffle. How can I cope with getting an activation notification on deactivation?

Comment: It seems that 3 notifications are fired in rapid succession: willResignActive / didBecomeActive / willResignActive.

Comment: Just a quick thing to test - what happens if you do this test say on an ipad pro and attempt to switch apps?

Comment: @solenoid Not an iPad app. No problem in any other iPhone, just iPhone X.

Comment: @MartinR So in theory we could work around this with some wild and crazy timing / debounce mechanism.

Comment: Why does it confuse your app? It behaves as if the app was deactivated, then activated and deactivated again – which is something that *could* have happened.

Comment: @matt I only ask to see if its the same behavior that ipad multitasking exhibits as being the cause

Comment: @MartinR That's true, I could solve it by reversing in deactivate what I did on activate. And you could reasonably argue that my failing to do that was a kind of bug all along. But I still see Apple's behavior here as a bug.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a bug. But your question was "How can I cope with it", and handling *both* (symmetric) notifications would be a solution to that. At least they come properly balanced!

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I agree. As you rightly say, we'd have the same problem if the user activated and quickly deactivated.

Comment: This seems happening only for 11.x OS onwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact there are three notifications fired in rapid succession when the application is deactivated in the iPhone X Simulator:

1. UIApplicationWillResignActive
2. UIApplicationDidBecomeActive
3. UIApplicationWillResignActive

This is wrong (and you might want to file a bug report), but it is something that *could* happen if a user
deactivates - activates – deactivates the app quickly, so the app
should cope with that situation anyway.

Both notifications must be handled in a symmetric fashion (and they come properly balanced, even with that bug): Actions done
on "activate" must be reversed on "deactivate".

Comment: I now find that this happens on any device when the user brings down the notification center from the top of the screen.