# AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess presents unexpected behavior with a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, avcapturedevice

**Working with Xcode 10.1 and Swift 4.2**

I have a complex app that uses a `UINavigationController` implemented in the `AppDelegate`.

The rootViewController of the navigationController is a `DashboardController()` class (subclass of `UIViewController`)

The `DashboardController` implements a left menu drawer using several ViewControllers (with `self.addChild(viewController)`)

Everything works fine, except when I need to push a viewController to present a `BarCodeScannerView().`

The barebone barCodeScannerView can be **pushed** and **popped** as expected.

The problems arises when I request access to the camera (only the first time).

1. As soon as I present the `Device.requestAccess(for:)` as follow: the viewController is **popped** and the previous view (rootViewController) is presented.   (Still with the "App would like to access the camera" AlertView)

   func requestCameraAccess() {
       AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) { granted in
           if granted {
               self.launchScanner()
           } else {
               self.goBack()
           }
       }
   }
2. If I click "OK" The system will register that the access was granted, but the 
   `applicationDidBecomeActive` (in the `AppDelegate`) is called after aprox 1 second.    I have some initializers in `applicationDidBecomeActive`, and they all are executed again.   And after a quick delay, everything works fine.

BTW: `applicationWillResignActive`, `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillEnterForeground` are NOT called. So it is clear that this is not part of an App LifeCycle.

Any idea what might me going on here?    What can make the system call `applicationDidBecomeActive` within the app? and still keep everything running?

Thx in advance...

**UPDATE**   After reading the comments, I was able to isolate the issue #2 as follows:

A simple/barebones project with a `UINavigationController` with a dashboardViewController as `rootViewController`. The dashboardViewController pushes a `CameraViewController()` in `viewDidLoad()`. The cameraViewController requests access to the camera.  When clicking OK, the call to `applicationDidBecomeActive` is triggered.

The full project is attached. (except the "Privacy - Camera Usage Description" key in the .plist.

```
import UIKit
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow? = UIWindow()
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let dashboardViewController = DashboardViewController()
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: dashboardViewController)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        print("applicationDidBecomeActive")
    }
    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {}
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {}
    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {}
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {}
}
class DashboardViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let cameraVC = CameraViewController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cameraVC, animated: true)
    }
}
import AVFoundation
class CameraViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) { granted in
            if granted {
                print("Access granted")
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: "So it is clear that this is not part of an App LifeCycle" It's not clear at all. Unless you are (wrongly) calling `didBecomeActive`, only the runtime can call it, and it calls it because we became active.

Comment: However, I think we should concentrate first on this: "As soon as I present the Device.requestAccess(for:) as follow: the viewController is popped and the previous view (rootViewController) is presented. (Still with the "App would like to access the camera" AlertView)" That's wrong and you should think about why you're doing that. Once that request for authorization is summoned, nothing should happen until you receive the async result. So you need to concentrate on why this popping is happening behind the authorization dialog.

Comment: Thx @matt.   After reading your comments, I am suspecting that this is related to the fact that I have several ViewControllers managed by the DashboardController (using addChild(viewController))...    BTW... The call to  didBecomeActive is triggered by the runTime.    I checked my code to ensure that I am not calling it, and also added an observer to the .didBecomeActiveNotification notification to verify it.

Comment: Hi @matt   I created a fresh barebones project to replicate the issue and I found a couple things:  1. The popping of the ViewController is not related to the .requestAccess to the camera   2.- It is also not related the usage of viewControllers as child of the root viewController.     I was able to replicate the issue #2 with a simple NavController that pushes a simple UIViewController and requesting access in viewDidLoad triggers the call to applicationDidBecomeActive.  I will add the code to the question.....

Comment: Hmmm, you should probably not be requesting access in view did load at all, because your view controller's view is not in the interface yet. So if that's the issue, try not doing that. In any case I'll be glad to look at the bare bones project if you post it on github or similar.

Comment: @matt. I added the code in the question...  Also, asking for access in viewDidAppear() has the same result... I am using Xcode 10.1 (10B61)

Comment: That's great, let me think about this for a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the problem is just with your testing procedure. When I run your code with a `print` statement in `applicationWillResignActive`, this is what I see:

```
applicationDidBecomeActive
applicationWillResignActive
Access granted
applicationDidBecomeActive
```

That seems completely in order and normal. It would have been weird to get a spurious `didBecomeActive`, but that is not what's happening; we resign active and then become active again, which is fine. You should expect that at any time your app can resign active and become active again. Many things in the normal lifecycle can cause that, and the presentation of an out-of-process dialog like the authorization dialog can reasonably be one of them. You should write your code in such a way as to cope with that possibility.

Comment: I had also put a print() in applicationWillResignActive, but for some reason, I overlooked at it......    Now. With that in mind, the conclusion is that requesting access to the camera disables the app momentarily, something that is not clear in the app lifecycle documentation...  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle   I don't see the alert view as an "interruption", but we will have to manage it.     At least I have learned something... Thx...

Comment: In a way your question reminds me of mine here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46350524/applicationdidbecomeactive-firing-on-deactivation-on-iphone-x But lots of things can cause the app to "blink off and on" - on iPad the user could change our size in multitasking mode, a phone call could come in, the user could summon the control center and dismiss it, the user could switch to the app switcher interface and come back, etc. Your code needs to be in the right place. If you were assuming the app would active just once, at launch, that was just a wrong assumption.