# iPhone X calls fake applicationWillResignActive and then applicationDidBecomeActive shortly afterwards

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, iphone-x

I see that my app gets a call to `applicationWillResignActive` and then almost immediately to `applicationDidBecomeActive` for no apparent reason, only on iPhone X-family devices. The delay between these 2 events is 0.05 to 1-2 sec. My guess is that it may be because of the slight touches in the bottom of the screen, which trigger task switcher at first, and then, as the touch ends with no drag, task switcher cancels its action.

Looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46350524/applicationdidbecomeactive-firing-on-deactivation-on-iphone-x) it looks like this could explain the reason for the extra notifications there as well.

Any ideas on why exactly this happens and how to reliably filter it out?

In my case, the app runs in Unity, and Unity will freeze the managed code 1 frame after applicationWillResignActive comes in, so there's no chance to launch a timer and get it in 1 sec of being in the background in managed code.  Even though I can filter out `OnApplicationFocus()` with `hasFocus==true`, I can't do the same with `hasFocus==false` because of it.